# Custom monthly graph

Tags: php, jquery, graph, charts

[image]

I need to create a custom chart as shown. Can anyone suggest a library for doing this? I've used highcharts in the past, but never seen one quite like this.

I'm not opposed to doing it from scratch if I have to, but I was hoping somebody had a suggestion.

I'm using php on the backend and jquery on the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/) has tons of chart types and it's pretty intuitive.
If you want to totally customize the chart then [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) lets you control every aspect of it, though you'd be building a chart from scratch.
[Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) is another one if you want to work from scratch.

Comment: I just may have to go with google, looks good and the free part never hurts. I'm also looking at [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/) since I'm already using jQuery. Thanks!

Comment: I've used HighCharts before and I definitely prefer Google Charts, the API makes more sense to me

Comment: its only free, if you don't use it a lot